# How do I replace something in the hierarchy in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, hierarchy

I recently started 3-D modelling in Unity, but before I did so, I created a quick gun model which doesn't look too good. And it has some scripts and components on it. And now I want to replace it with one I made in Blender. How do I replace that in the hierarchy of Unity?

Comment: If the hierarchy of the model is the same and you want to keep the same import settings, you can just replace the asset outside of Unity directly with the new asset if it has the exact same name. It will update the fbx while keeping the references it has.

Comment: In general I go with: Keep all behaviors/components on empty objects, put meshes as child object of these => you can at any time exchange the child mesh objects without having to replace any behaviour references